# Add progress bar in Material-UI table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I have this example of Material-UI table:

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import {
  createStyles,
  lighten,
  makeStyles,
  Theme
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import FilterListIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FilterList";

interface Data {
  calories: number;
  carbs: number;
  fat: number;
  name: string;
  protein: number;
}

function createData(
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  fat: number,
  carbs: number,
  protein: number
): Data {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Donut", 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Honeycomb", 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Jelly Bean", 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
  createData("KitKat", 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
  createData("Lollipop", 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
  createData("Marshmallow", 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
  createData("Nougat", 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
  createData("Oreo", 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0)
];

function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

type Order = "asc" | "desc";

function getComparator<Key extends keyof any>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: Key
): (
  a: { [key in Key]: number | string },
  b: { [key in Key]: number | string }
) => number {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort<T>(array: T[], comparator: (a: T, b: T) => number) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index] as [T, number]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

interface HeadCell {
  disablePadding: boolean;
  id: keyof Data;
  label: string;
  numeric: boolean;
}

const headCells: HeadCell[] = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Dessert (100g serving)"
  },
  { id: "calories", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Calories" },
  { id: "fat", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Fat (g)" },
  { id: "carbs", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Carbs (g)" },
  { id: "protein", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Protein (g)" }
];

interface EnhancedTableProps {
  classes: ReturnType<typeof useStyles>;
  numSelected: number;
  onRequestSort: (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>,
    property: keyof Data
  ) => void;
  onSelectAllClick: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  order: Order;
  orderBy: string;
  rowCount: number;
}

function EnhancedTableHead(props: EnhancedTableProps) {
  const {
    classes,
    onSelectAllClick,
    order,
    orderBy,
    numSelected,
    rowCount,
    onRequestSort
  } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property: keyof Data) => (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>
  ) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "normal"}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingRight: theme.spacing(1)
    },
    highlight:
      theme.palette.type === "light"
        ? {
            color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
            backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85)
          }
        : {
            color: theme.palette.text.primary,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark
          },
    title: {
      flex: "1 1 100%"
    }
  })
);

interface EnhancedTableToolbarProps {
  numSelected: number;
}

const EnhancedTableToolbar = (props: EnhancedTableToolbarProps) => {
  const classes = useToolbarStyles();
  const { numSelected } = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0
      })}
    >
      {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="inherit"
          variant="subtitle1"
          component="div"
        >
          {numSelected} selected
        </Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          variant="h6"
          id="tableTitle"
          component="div"
        >
          Nutrition
        </Typography>
      )}
      {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <Tooltip title="Delete">
          <IconButton aria-label="delete">
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      ) : (
        <Tooltip title="Filter list">
          <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
            <FilterListIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      )}
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: "100%"
    },
    paper: {
      width: "100%",
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    table: {
      minWidth: 750
    },
    visuallyHidden: {
      border: 0,
      clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
      height: 1,
      margin: -1,
      overflow: "hidden",
      padding: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      top: 20,
      width: 1
    }
  })
);

export default function Hello() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState<Order>("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState<keyof Data>("calories");
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

  const handleRequestSort = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>,
    property: keyof Data
  ) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const handleSelectAllClick = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
      setSelected(newSelecteds);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, name: string) => {
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(name);
    let newSelected: string[] = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event: unknown, newPage: number) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const isSelected = (name: string) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

  const emptyRows =
    rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={"medium"}
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.name}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox
                          checked={isItemSelected}
                          inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        id={labelId}
                        scope="row"
                        padding="none"
                      >
                        {row.name}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-leaf-d0zy2?file=/src/Hello.tsx:0-12181

Do you know how I can add a progress bar like this one into the table:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      '& > * + *': {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
      },
    },
  }),
);

export default function CircularIndeterminate() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CircularProgress />
      <CircularProgress color="secondary" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ref: https://material-ui.com/components/progress/

I would like to see a progress bar while data is loading from Rest API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of such use case:

when the backend API is called we set loading to true to show the progress bar and when it finishes we set loading to false to "turn it off"

```
import React from "react";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";
export default function App() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const apiCall = () => {
        setLoading(true)
        axios.get("url")
        .then(response => {
            useData(response);
            }
        )
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false)
            }
        );
    }

    return (
    <div>
        { loading ?? <CircularProgress />}
        <RestOfApplication/>
    </div>
    );
}
```

In this sandbox in an example for showing the progress while an API call is being made on page load:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-example-of-circular-progress-while-api-call-z10gp

relevant snippets:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const wait = (ms: number | undefined) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  var chain = Promise.resolve();

  const apiCall = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    // axios
    //   .get("url")
    //   .then((response) => {
    //     useData(response);
    //   })
    chain = chain
      .then(() => {
        console.log("api call");
        return wait(7000);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall();
  }, []);

........


<Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            alignItems: "center",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            width: "100vw"
          }}
        >
          <CircularProgress />
        </div>
      ) : (
        []
      )}
      <RestOfApplication/>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Can you show me how to implement this into the code from the sandbox?

Comment: updated my answer please check if that helps you

Comment: Do you know is it possible to implement he progress bar at the center of the table?

Comment: made the appropriate changes, notice though that if you want it in a different "middle" you'd just need to move it around to your liking

Comment: I tried this one: https://pastebin.com/xA2PyC4D But I get `TypeScript error in C:/Users/cms/ts/src/pages/business-customers/AllBusinessCustomers.tsx(307,7):
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.  TS2349

    305 |   useEffect(() => {
    306 |     const getData = async () => {
  > 307 |       setLoading(true);` Any idea why?`

Comment: also, from looking at the code in the link it looks like you didn't break the `useState` to value and function but only function `const [setLoading] = useState(false);`, see [this](https://pastebin.com/xA2PyC4D) link at line 302

Comment: yes, I get `TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.` fir this line `setLoading(true);` Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @PeterPenzov please refer to my previous comment, your `useState` isn't like mine and is problematic. I suspect your issue derives from that (being `setLoading` in the code you sent isn't as I designed it at first)

Comment: Looks like I'm having an issue somewhere. Can we try to update this code with REST API data: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ueeenr?file=Hello.tsx so we can implement it properly, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Are we still on the same issue as the original question?

Comment: Yes, I added the code with real API call to test the code with real test data.

Comment: What I mean is, are we still talking about how to *Add progress bar in Material-UI table*? cause if not I'm, afraid it would require a different question to not oversaturate this thread

Comment: Yes, I added Rest API call in order to make full example with the progress bar.

Comment: ok but the new issue is regarding the integration, not the execution. on top of it, there's no usage of the progress or loading keywords. if one of the answers solved the original issue you should accept it, otherwise I suggest waiting for a better solution.

Comment: Ok, I agree that this is additional issue. Can you show me into my latest code how to properly implement the progress bar, please?

Comment: I'll try but I havent used typescript much, if I find a solution I'll update the answer. is the latest code version in this link stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ueeenr?file=Hello.tsx ?

Comment: The issue is SSL connectivity: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackblitz.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://185.185.126.15:8080/api/merchants/onboarding/task?page=1&size=100'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Please if you can test the code locally so you can implement the progress bar.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a loading with position `absolute` to show it in the center of the table.

And after that using a state to control show/hide this loading when fetching data from API

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-lamport-ct3k4?file=/src/loading.tsx

Comment: I tried to apply it but I get always displayed progress bar. Not only for Rest API loading time.

Comment: And after that using a state to control show/hide this loading when fetching data from API

Comment: @PeterPenzov There's no API call anywhere in your code example, so that part is on you to figure out.

Comment: Can you show me how to implement it please?

Comment: You can add something like this `{ toShow ?? <RoundProgress/>}` in the return\render section

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import { Stack, Typography, CircularProgress } from '@mui/material';

...

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query GetPage($slug: String!) {
    pageBySlug(slug: $slug) {
      id
      slug
      Title
      Content
    
  }, {
    variables: {
      slug: slug,
    },
  });

  if (loading) {
    return  <Stack alignItems="center">
      <CircularProgress sx={{ m: 1 }} color="primary" />
      <Typography
        sx={{
          display: 'inline-block',
          color: 'primary.main',
          p: 1,
        }}
      >
        Data is loading...
      </Typography>
    </Stack>
  }
  if (error) {
    return <Error />;
  }
```

...

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {page.Seo && <Head props={page.Seo} slug={page.slug} />}
      {page.Hero && <Hero props={page.Hero} />}
      <Container
        sx={{
          py: 10,
        }}
      >
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h1" sx={{ mb: 10 }}>
          {page.Title}
        </Typography>
        <Container
          sx={{
            width: { md: '75%' },
          }}
        >
          <ReactMarkdown>{page.Content}</ReactMarkdown>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```